# ngOptions Erroring when data is returned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angular-services, angularjs-ng-options

`console.log` in the controller is outputting the object `{name:'12345235'}` which is fine but trying to use the `ng-option` attribute in the HTML section gives the below error, I've tried returning multiple nested objects from the service but still get the below error in the console, any tips/help appreciated, stumped at this stage, not sure what else I can try?

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="app">
...
<body>
    ...
    <div ng-controller="SetsController">
        <section ng-options="set in sets"><p>{{set.name}}</p></section>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Angular code:

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('SetsController', ['$scope', 'setsService', function($scope, setsService){
    $scope.sets = setsService.display('123', 3);
    console.log($scope.sets);
}]);

angular.module('app').service('setsService', function(){
    this.display = function(setId, limit) {
        return {name:'12345235'}
    }
});
```

Console Error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$compile/ctreq?p0=select&p1=ngOptions
I/<@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:6:416
t@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:59:233
t@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:59:300
K@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:62:78
g@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:54:410
K@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:61:1
g@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:54:410
g@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:54:433
g@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:54:433
g@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:54:433
g@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:54:433
W/<@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:53:480
zc/d/</<@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:20:99
lf/this.$get</n.prototype.$eval@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:133:217
lf/this.$get</n.prototype.$apply@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:133:446
zc/d/<@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:20:57
e@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:39:191
zc/d@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:19:1
zc@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:20:274
Zd@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:19:83
@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:293:238
a@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:174:399
Hf/c@http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js:35:212

http://devt.local.one/core/lib/angular.js
Line 107
```

Comment: ng-options should be used with select tag . see [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) documentation. In this case you need to use ng-repeat

Comment: @MaheSirius Ah yes, `ng-repeat`, that's what happens when you look at the same code for too long, thanks, working now!

Comment: welcome :). i  will post it as answer and pls accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngOptions` directive requires `select` directive. It cannot be used by its own. So you should either use proper structure with select tag instead of section (and don't forget `ngModel` too in this case) or use `ngRepeat`:

```
<div ng-controller="SetsController">
    <section ng-repeat="set in sets"><p>{{set.name}}</p></section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

ng-options should be used with select tag . see ng-options documentation. In this case you need to use ng-repeat

eg,

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors">
   <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
</select>
```

in your case you need to use ng-repeat as,

```
<section ng-repeat="set in sets"><p>{{set.name}}</p></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error because i dont have `ng-model` attribute in `<select>`